# /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace_marker Bad file descriptor error

Tags: linux, file-descriptor, ftrace

Im trying to do

> echo "FINN" > /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace_marker

inside the shell (ubuntu 14) as root and im getting the next error

> bash: echo: write error: Bad file descriptor

I dont know what is wrong, I read how to do it [here](https://lwn.net/Articles/366796/) and [here](http://blog.fpmurphy.com/2014/05/kernel-tracing-using-ftrace.html) (articles about how using **ftrace**)

Other **ftrace** files that I had to write into worked fine...

Answer (score 1):

You might have run

```
echo 0 to tracing_on
```

You can run

```
echo 1 > tracing_on
```

and

```
echo something > trace_marker
```

and it should work again.